# Calculando um intervalo de tempo com a função LAG()

Tags: mysql, sql, query, oracle, sqldeveloper

Gostaria de calcular um intervalo de tempo no SQLDeveloper, entre a penultima compra e a ultima compra.

Por exemplo:

1. Compra1 : 20/07/2022
2. Compra2 : 21/07/2022
3. Compra3 : 30/08/2022
4. Compra4 : 01/01/2023
5. Compra5 : 30/01/2023

Gostaria de saber o intervalo de tempo da compra4 até a compra5.

No postgresql eu consigo fazer tranquilamente com o seguinte código:

```
EXTRACT(day FROM (data - LAG(data,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC))) as diff
```

Um pedaço da minha query com o calculo de diferença errada:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS NUM_BUY,
LAG(DATA,1) OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS LAST_DATE,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATA) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM (LAG(DATA, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC))) AS DIFF,
    CPF,
    DATA
FROM
    CTE
```

Com esse código acima me retorna consulta errada.

E retorna valores negativos

Comment: 1) Informe apenas a TAG do SGBD em questão (mysql, oracle etc) , a implementações podem ter diferenças , 2) O que é "consulta errada" , diferenças podem ser negativas , se dia 1 foi 100 e dia 90 a diferença e -10 3) Se possível publique um exemplo no http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de resolver isso seria usando o `LAG` para retornar a linha anterior numa *subquery*, e a seguir calcular a diferença, assim por exemplo:

```
SELECT sub.*,
       DATEDIFF(sub.data_compra, sub.data_compra_anterio) diferenca
FROM  (SELECT id,
              data_compra,
              LAG(data_compra,1) OVER w AS data_compra_anterior
         FROM datas
        WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY data_compra)) AS sub
```

Aqui "sub" é o alias da *subquery*, que retona "data_compra" e "data_compra_anterior", que foi obtida usando a função [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) (usei explicatamente o `1` para uma linha anterior, mas esse é o valor padrão e poderia ser omitido.

A seguir, foi usada função [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) para calcular a diferença entre a data anterior e a atual, retornadas na subquery.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/un7WD2BQQHry3rMdQA9VAE/0)

Notas:

- Pode mudar o `DATEDIFF` para tratar horas, minutos, etc, veja a documentação.
- Pode tratar valores negativos mudando o `ORDER` ou no resultado de `DATEDIFF`